# Possible to set Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax for all calendars in the appDomain?

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering if it is possible to set System.Globalization.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax for all calendars in the current appDomain.

I'm using a third party library (FileHelpers csv parser) which can parse two digit years, and need more control over how 2 digit years in the csv file are being interpreted.

I'm aware that you can set instances of Calendar object's TwoDigitYearMax property, but my problem is that it is not easy (or possible ?) to pass the required Calendar instance to the third party library.

Comment: I guess you can use `Session` variable to hold your value and whenever you use Calender in your application, use session value.